# Failed to save in SQLite database django

Tags: python, django

I have the following codes:

models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):

    jobname = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    enabled = models.BooleanField()
    freq_type = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    freq_interval = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    freq_recurrence = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    start_date=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    end_date=models.CharField(max_length=10, blank = True)
    start_time=models.CharField(max_length=6)
    end_time=models.CharField(max_length=6, blank = True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null = True)
    date_modified=models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, null = True)
    version=models.IntegerField(default = 1)

class Job_removed(models.Model):

    jobname = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(null = True)
    freq_type = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    freq_interval = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    freq_recurrence = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    start_date=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    end_date=models.CharField(max_length=10, blank = True)
    start_time=models.CharField(max_length=6)
    end_time=models.CharField(max_length=6, blank = True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
    date_modified=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    version=models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

views.py

```
def job_delete(request,pk):
    job=Job.objects.get(pk=pk)
    jobdetail = Job_detail.objects.get(job=pk)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        jobr = JobRemovedForm(request.POST)
        
        if jobr.is_valid():
            jobr.jobname = job.jobname
            print(jobr.jobname)
            jobr.owner = job.owner
            print(jobr.owner)
            jobr.enabled = job.enabled
            print(jobr.enabled)
            jobr.start_date = job.start_date
            print(jobr.start_date)
            jobr.start_time = job.start_time
            print(jobr.start_time)
            jobr.date_added = job.date_added
            print(jobr.date_added)
            jobr.version = job.version
            print(jobr.version)
            jobr.save()
            return redirect('/job/', {'job':Job.objects.all})
        else:
            jobr = JobRemovedForm()
           
            return render(request, 'interface/job_removed.html', {'job':job, 'jobdetail':jobdetail, 'jobr':jobr})
    return render(request, 'interface/job_removed.html', {'job':job, 'jobdetail':jobdetail})
```

Output of my powershell for those print commands:

[image]

In the database (SQLite):

[image]

What I am trying to do is to copy from the entry from `Job Table` to `Job_removed Table`. I assign the new entry in `Job_removed` with the values in `Job Table`. It is printing correctly in my powershell but when I check my database, none of the value are entering. Why is this happening though? Can anyone explain to me and point me to the right direction to correct this? I know there are post about how to clone data to another table but it does not fit the task that I am required to do so I am not using those answers.

Update: model for Job_detail and form for JobRemovedForm

models.py

```
class Job_detail(models.Model):
    job_type=models.IntegerField(default=1)
    json = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
class JobRemovedForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job_removed
        fields = []
```

Update 2: views (I realize i didnt do `commit=False`)  and form fields updated

views.py

```
def job_delete(request,pk):
    job=Job.objects.get(pk=pk)
    jobdetail = Job_detail.objects.get(job=pk)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        jobr = JobRemovedForm(request.POST)
        
        if jobr.is_valid():
            jr = jobr.save(commit=False)
            jr.jobname = job.jobname
            print(jr.jobname)
            jr.owner = job.owner
            print(jr.owner)
            jr.enabled = job.enabled
            print(jr.enabled)
            jr.start_date = job.start_date
            print(jr.start_date)
            jr.start_time = job.start_time
            print(jr.start_time)
            jr.date_added = job.date_added
            print(jr.date_added)
            jr.version = job.version
            print(jr.version)
            jr.save()
            return redirect('/job/', {'job':Job.objects.all})
        else:
            print(jobr.errors)
            jobr = JobRemovedForm()
            
            return render(request, 'interface/job_removed.html', {'job':job, 'jobdetail':jobdetail, 'jobr':jobr})
    return render(request, 'interface/job_removed.html', {'job':job, 'jobdetail':jobdetail})
```

forms.py

```
class JobRemovedForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job_removed
        fields = ['jobname', 'owner', 'enabled', 'start_date', 'start_time', 'date_added', 'version']
```

And now my powershell is showing `jobr.errors` of the following:

jobname

This field is required.

owner

This field is required.

start_date

This field is required.

start_time

This field is required.

date_added

This field is required.

version

This field is required.

Comment: What is Job_detail model ?

Comment: Hi, I just updated the post with the Job_detail model and also the form for JobRemovedForm

Comment: do you want an other solution for this problem you are not actually doing right ? why do you need Job_detail ?

Comment: Why do you copy entries from Job to Job_removed instead of having a `removed` field on the `Job`?

Comment: Please do, I am a beginner and I am trying to learn how to do it right. Also for job_detail, it is needed due to the things I am showing in my html for this view. @amadousow

Comment: The copying of the entries is not what I wanted but what my colleague tasked me to do @AKX. But from my understanding, do you mean saving like True/False in this ```removed``` field on ```Job```. And in the html, if it is True, do not display

Comment: I have also updated my post on the views and forms under update 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you do not need Job_removed model because it is unuseful and not better design for a such case in general.so first **remove** that model and add a field called `is_deleted` to your job model which value should be `True` for deleted jobs and `False` for non deleted jobs.by default i make `is_deleted` is `False` so when you deleted it you can mark it as `True`

```
class Job(models.Model):

    jobname = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    enabled = models.BooleanField()
    freq_type = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    freq_interval = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    freq_recurrence = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    start_date=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    end_date=models.CharField(max_length=10, blank = True)
    start_time=models.CharField(max_length=6)
    end_time=models.CharField(max_length=6, blank = True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null = True)
    date_modified=models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, null = True)
    version=models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    is_delete = models.BooleanField(default=False) # new field
```

1. Delete your model remove Job_removed
   2)run `python manage.py makemigrations`
   3)run `python manage.py migrate`

now let us work on your views for deleting jobs.

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
def job_delete(request,pk):
    job= get_object_or_404(Job,pk=pk,is_deleted=False)
    job.is_deleted = True # delete the job if it is not deleted 
    job.save()
    return redirect('/job/')
```

**Note**:I use `get_object_or_404` to raise page not found if there is no job related to the pk and i check that the job is not deleted.

now i do not know how is your other views but you should now make a little bit of change in querying jobs.if you want to query all jobs you should query jobs that is not deleted.by doing this

```
Job.objects.filter(is_deleted = False)
```

instead of

```
Job.objects.all()
```

and better approach should be to use post method for deleting jobs not get.but for now you can keep as it is.
sorry for my english if you do not understand please ask me in the comments.
**Update** 
but if you want to do is it as you did.
then you do not need a form you can just copy the data from Job to Job_removed.and if you need a form you can make these fields read only.
**let us do it without form**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
def job_delete(request,pk):
    job= get_object_or_404(Job,pk=pk)
    jr = Job_removed()
    jr.jobname = job.jobname
    print(jr.jobname)
    jr.owner = job.owner
    print(jr.owner)
    jr.enabled = job.enabled
    print(jr.enabled)
    jr.start_date = job.start_date
    print(jr.start_date)
    jr.start_time = job.start_time
    print(jr.start_time)
    jr.date_added = job.date_added
    print(jr.date_added)
    jr.version = job.version
    print(jr.version)
    jr.save()
    job.delete() # then delete the job
    return redirect('/job/')
```

Comment: First, a very big thank you for teaching me how to do it for both ways. It let me understand how to do it differently. Unfortunately, what my colleague wants is using my way so I used the function you corrected.  Secondly, what is I have another table. It has the field for foreign key to link to this ```job_removed``` table. How do i deal with it? I tried to call the table and assign it to lets say ```example```. I then code it as example.job = jr. And i got the error of cannot be assign. Must be Job Instance. How do i fix this?

Comment: @L.Calvin could you please update your question with that new model design you make so that i can see what you have done so far.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I managed to solve it. I was careless in creating the same table for ```removed```.  But thank you very much for guiding me in this !

Answer (score 1):

Form is not required in this situation.

**Soft delete is the best option.**  [Have a look in to this tutorial](https://dev.to/bikramjeetsingh/soft-deletes-in-django-a9j)

Comment: I am unsure of the approach for ```CreateView``` so I followed the advise on all the fields I want. But now my powershell is showing that I am not filling those fields up but before, my powershell is showing the variables are taking the values. I am confused. I updated my views and form under ```update 2```

Comment: Thats because your are setting the values in `is_valid()` method which is triggered if the validation succeeds. You should set the form values during form initialisation (`jobr = JobRemovedForm(request.POST,  initial={"jobname": job.jobname, ....})`. In your case `CreateVeiw` also will not make sense since using form is not at all required. Try using soft delete.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I got what I needed in the output already